# Insert row into a table with foreign key inside PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a PHP website that use Apache web server (PHPmyAdmin)

I have 3 tables :

1. brand

   - brand_id (PRIMARY KEY) AUTO INCREMENT
   - brand_name
2. item

   - item_id (PRIMARY KEY) AUTO INCREMENT
   - item_category
3. model

   - model_id (PRIMARY KEY) AUTO INCREMENT
   - item_model
   - brand_id (FOREIGN KEY for brand.brand_id)
   - brand_name (FOREIGN KEY for item.item_id)
   - quantity
   - price

I have a problem when I want to insert new value into model table.

this is PHP Code that I use for inserting

```
if (isset($_POST['brand_id']));
    $brand = ($_POST['brand_id']);
if (isset($_POST['item_id']));
    $cat = ($_POST['item_id']);
if (isset($_POST['model']));
    $model = ($_POST['model']);
if (isset($_POST['quantity']))
    $quantity = ($_POST['quantity']);
if (isset($_POST['price']))
    $price = ($_POST['price']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO model (item_model, brand_id, item_id, quantity, price)
                VALUES ('$model', '$brand', '$cat', '$quantity', '$price')";
```

Note that I did not insert any value into the model_id because I think it will automatically increased for it is AUTO increment. I dont know whether I am right or wrong.
the isset values are passed from another PHP file. so this PHP basically just catch the thrown values from previous PHP file.

I had tried to insert value directly from the PHPmyAdmin using SQL statement and it yielded this error :

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key 
constraint fails (`stock`.`model`, CONSTRAINT `fk_item_brand` 
FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brand` (`brand_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

and if I tried to put in a id value into one of the column, it will yield an error:

```
SQL query:

INSERT INTO `model`(`model_id`, `item_model`, `brand_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`, `price`) 
VALUES (1,'a','1','1','a','a')

MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How do I insert a row into a table with foreign key inside PHP?

Comment: "I have a problem" -- what is the problem? You're doing auto increment correctly.

Comment: You're right, you don't need to include the auto increment value. What I really don't like is how you insert URL arguments directly into your SQL command. Do NOT do this, EVER. Read more about SQL injection here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: you have some extra semi-colons in there at the end of your `if` statements. They could be the issue. Or perhaps it might fail if one of your variables is not instantiated because the corresponding `$_POST` variable was not set. In any case, I'd be checking what is passed to this page via `POST` (e.g. type and/or length), perhaps using `filter_var()` and also I would use prepared statements and bind the values to the statement.

Comment: btw if that exactly query are you doing ... than your code is open for sql injection no matter what are you using to query

Comment: please check my newest post. I have provided new info

Comment: your first error  a foreign key 
constraint fails (`stock`.`model`, CONSTRAINT `fk_item_brand` 
FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brand` (`brand_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)  means that the key is not available in primary table which you are trying to insert here.

Comment: I hope your `brand` and `item` tables are not empty and to your model table you put values from those tables?

Comment: Now I have problem with the duplicate for PRIMARY KEY, can anybody help me please? Tell me what to do??

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO model (model_id,item_model, brand_id, item_id, quantity, price)
                VALUES (null,'$model', '$brand', '$cat', '$quantity', '$price')";
```

Try this.

Add auto increment field and pass value null

Comment: Leaving out the column is the same as inserting `NULL` into it.

Comment: what what is the difference between your query and query in question ?